# using animations properly in angular when ng-if

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have this simple code: (it's rendering 'pages' from my db)

```
<div ng-repeat='page in pages' >
            <div ng-if="$index == pageToShow">
                <h2> {{page.title}} </h2>
                <div ng-repeat='quest in page.quests'>
                    <div ng-switch on="quest.ui.type">
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-select-single" >
                            <div ms-select-single quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-select-multy">
                            <div ms-select-multy quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-date">
                            <div ms-date quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-text">
                            <div ms-text quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-textarea">
                            <div ms-textarea quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-number">
                            <div ms-number quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="ms-html">
                            <div ms-html quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                         <div ng-switch-when="ms-video">
                            <div ms-video quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                         <div ng-switch-when="ms-iframe">
                            <div ms-iframe quest='quest'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="padQuests"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can I do really simple animation, when one ng-if kicks in and the other goes out? because what I had right now is the following:

the page that's leaving is bouncing out and the one entering is bouncing in fast (beneath the one that's there for a moment)...

What library should I use to do so?

Comment: I suggest you look into ng-animate

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a project called [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

> animate.css is a bunch of cool, fun, and cross-browser animations for you to use in your projects. Great for emphasis, home pages, sliders, and general just-add-water-awesomeness.

Comment: Problem still persist, when an animation occures, the .ng-leave happens in the same time .ng-enter happens, so the next page comes beneath the page that is allready there (it's doing fadeout..still not out)

Comment: @totothegreat I suggest you post a working plnkr/jsfiddle with your current code